# Laravel return and redirect to view from function called using POST request

Tags: laravel, view

In my `web.php` I've got POST route:

```
Route::post('/view-all/{model?}', [SearchController::class,'viewAll']);
```

I am trying to return a view from this function and it looks like this:

```
public function viewAll(Request $request) 
{
   //code
   ...
   return view('search::single', ['searchResults' => $searchResults, 'query' => $q, 'type' => $type));

}
```

And in JavaScript I get returned view successfully, but the I am not being redirected to the page which should contain the `html` of returned `view`.

I saw couple of similar questions here and it is suggested that I should create another `GET` route which should call a function whose only job would be to return a view. But the problem is that I should pass multiple parameters to that view, which I don't want to be passed through URL, but I do not know what would be the other solution when using GET method

This is how I call the route:

```
fetch('/view-all/' + searchData.model.replace('_', '-'), {
   headers: {
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
   "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
   },
   method: 'POST',
   credentials: "same-origin",
   body: JSON.stringify({'ids': searchData.ids})
})
```

Comment: How are you calling that route, with ajax?

Comment: Will add that piece of code immediately

Comment: you need to explain more, is that jquery, vuejs etc?

Comment: I'm not using any framework on front, `vanilla js` it is. I don't think if this classifies as ajax, but it's a [fetch function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)